# In Portrait View getting Null Pointer Exception

Tags: android, camera, nullpointerexception

My app works fine when i am using this in a Landscape Mode, but whenever i use my app in Portrait Mode getting Null Pointer Exception

**Log:**

```
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.camera/com.example.camera.CameraLauncherActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3576)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:140)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1243)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1036)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:803)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at com.example.camera.CameraLauncherActivity.onCreate(CameraLauncherActivity.java:103)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5191)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
12-12 17:37:34.865: E/AndroidRuntime(20671):    ... 12 more
```

**Line Number 103 is:**

```
captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

**CameraLauncherActivity.java:-**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    mCamera = getCameraInstance();

    mCameraPreview = new PreviewSurface(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);
    Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "captureButton :: "
            + captureButton);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            Log.d(CameraLauncherActivity.LOG_TAG, "mCamera.takePicture :: "
                    + mCamera);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: are u using different layouts folders?

Comment: make sure activity_camera layout has R.id.btnCapture View

Comment: @Monica yeah i am using two different - 2 folders, layout for Portrait, and layout-land for Landscape

Comment: :) cool ur layout is differing then just check the components and ids there u will get the answer

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah yeah thanks i did stupid mistake

Comment: @Monica yeah thanks i did stupid mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You either don't have `btnCapture` in Portrait mode or there is some spelling mistake in it.